# Trouble buffering a vector layer in QGIS with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis, buffer

I am working on a script that imports a .csv layer that has lat long coordinates, which I then want to buffer in feet.
I've created a vector layer from the .csv file and tried to set the coordinate system of the vector layer to a  local system with units in feet, but when I buffer that layer I don't get the expected output - it looks like its buffering in degrees. Is there a way to specify buffer units? I understand the units are determine by the input layer which I have tried to set to the local system.
 What am I doing wrong?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog
from qgis.utils import iface
import os

csvFile = QInputDialog.getText(None,'Enter .csv path','Enter filepath for csv:')

s = QSettings()
oldValidation = s.value("/Projections/defaultBehaviour")
s.setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal" )

InFlnm= os.path.split(csvFile[0])[1]
InDrPth= os.path.split(csvFile[0])[0].replace('\\','/')
InFlPth="file:///"+InDrPth+'/'+InFlnm

csvImport = InFlPth+"?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "Longitud", "Latitud")
shp = QgsVectorLayer(csvImport, InFlnm,"delimitedtext")
shp.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2239, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))

s.setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation)

buffFile = QInputDialog.getText(None,'Enter output filepath for buffer','Enter filepath for buffer:')
buffNm = os.path.split(buffFile[0])[1]
buffDir = os.path.split(buffFile[0])[0].replace('\\','/')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(shp)
mc = iface.mapCanvas() 
layer = mc.currentLayer()

QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, buffDir+'/'+buffNm, 60, False, False, -1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I needed to set the coordinate system of shp to WGS84, then write out to a new file and specify the local coordinate system - then add that layer to the map and buffer it. Worked! Here is my updated code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog
from qgis.utils import iface
import os
csvFile = QInputDialog.getText(None,'Enter .csv path','Enter filepath for csv:')

s = QSettings()
oldValidation = s.value("/Projections/defaultBehaviour")
s.setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal" )

InFlnm= os.path.split(csvFile[0])[1]
InDrPth= os.path.split(csvFile[0])[0].replace('\\','/')
InFlPth="file:///"+InDrPth+'/'+InFlnm

csvImport = InFlPth+"?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "Longitud", "Latitud")
shp = QgsVectorLayer(csvImport, InFlnm,"delimitedtext")
shp.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))

s.setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation)

buffFile = QInputDialog.getText(None,'Enter output filepath for buffer','Enter filepath for buffer:')
buffNm = os.path.split(buffFile[0])[1]
buffDir = os.path.split(buffFile[0])[0].replace('\\','/')

outPoints = 'c:/Temp/qgis/GPS_locations.shp'
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(shp, outPoints, "CP1250", sr, "ESRI Shapefile")
shpFt = QgsVectorLayer(outPoints, 'GPS_locations',"ogr")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(shpFt)
mc = iface.mapCanvas() 
layer = mc.currentLayer()

QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, buffDir+'/'+buffNm, 60, False, False, -1)
```

Comment: I know it is outdated now, but someone may need it as I did: above didn't work for me, and instead I first reprojected the geometry to some meter-based CRS, then did buffering and then reprojected back again to WGS-84 and after then I added the feature to the layer.